# How to interpret a linear mixed effect model with a logit transformed response variable?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, interpretation

I am running a linear mixed effect model to see how certain country level factors (i.e. malnutrition, income per capita, etc.) have affected country level TB case fatality ratio over the past 20 years. My data is longitudinal with repeat measures from countries. Because a case fatality ratio is bound between 0-1 I decided to apply a logit transformation to it to make it unbound. I am now struggling with what my interpretation of the model would be with my logit transformed CFR. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you basically have logistic regression but you’ve inferred both a global population parameter and sub-population parameters correct?

Comment: For example, you want to infer the causal effect of HFCS consumption on diabetes and your sub-populations are men and women. So you have one slope for men and one slope for women; however, both slopes are drawn from the same distribution; so the mean of this distribution tells you about the overall effect of HFCS consumption on diabetes. (Aka partial pooling design.)

Comment: Yes essentially. I am then building separate models with region specific data and in those models the random effect is the countries within those regions, there is no nested factor. The fixed factors are country characteristics that have been repeatedly measured over the past 20 years, namely prevalence of malnutrition, income per capita, and HIV incidence. I already have my model coefficients for those parameters and I am no trying determine how to interpret those coefficinets within the context of a logit transformed dependent variable.

Comment: So typically if the linear combination is passed through the logit function then the effect of interest is linear in log odds space. If $logit(a+bx)$ then $a+bx$ is linear in log odds.

Comment: The odds ratio can tell you whether the effect was significant in frequentist context or credible in a Bayesian context.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2938757/

Comment: Ok thank you, so then in my case what would the interpretation be for logit(y) = a+bx, because I only applied the logit to my dependent variable since it was originally bound between 0,1 but my independent variables are not bound. Does the interpretation you wrote above still apply

Comment: The independent variables should not be bound. The logit function does the binding for you. Essentially you just need to exponentiate the parameter of interest. $e^{parameter}$ to get the odds ratio. In the case of the slope, it gives you the increase in odds ratio of the outcome of interest given a 1 unit increase in independent variable that the parameter corresponds to.

Comment: So if the odds ratio, OR, equals 1 then outcome A is as likely as outcome A’ (not A.) OR >1 then exposure to the independent variable associated with greater likelihood of outcome A. OR<1 then exposure…associated with greater likelihood of outcome A’